# How do where one to three values ​come from the combo box in Eloquent Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a filter with three check boxes, each of which has a Value "question", "partnership", "complaint". but when I select two data from the check box (ex.complaint & question) sent to the controller and I use the orWhere function, the data is error (all appearing). Is what I'm doing wrong?

```
$data = BrandEnquiry::whereHas('brand', function($query) use ($post){
                $query->where('id_brand', '=' , $post['id_brand']);
            });

            if(isset($post['question'])){
                $data->where(function ($key) use ($post){
                    $key->orWhere('subject', 'LIKE', '%'.$post['question']);
                });
            }

              if(isset($post['complaint'])){
                $data->where(function($q)use($post){
                        $q->orWhere('subject', 'LIKE', '%'.$post['complaint']);

                    });

            }


            if(isset($post['partnership'])){
                $data->where(function($q)use($post){
                        $q->orWhere('subject', 'LIKE', '%'.$post['partnership']);

                    });

            }




            $data = $data->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
            ->with('brandOutlet')
            ->with('user')
            ->get();
```

and HTML

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 chxBox">
                    <label>Subject:</label>


                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="question" id="question" name="question">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                        Question
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="complaint" id="complaint" name="complaint">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                        Complaint
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="partnership" id="partnership" name="partnership" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                        Partnership
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to merge all `orWhere` together:

```
$data = BrandEnquiry::whereHas('brand', function($query) use ($post){
    $query->where('id_brand', '=' , $post['id_brand']);
});

$data->where(function ($key) use ($post){
    if(isset($post['question'])) 
        $key->where('subject', 'LIKE', '%'.$post['question']);
    if(isset($post['complaint']))
        $key->orWhere('subject', 'LIKE', '%'.$post['complaint']);
    if(isset($post['partnership']))
        $key->orWhere('subject', 'LIKE', '%'.$post['partnership']);
});


$data = $data->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
->with('brandOutlet')
->with('user')
->get();
```

Comment: Big Thanks bro. Solved

Answer (score 1):

You could use when method in laravel. The when method only executes the given Closure when the first parameter is true. If the first parameter is false, the Closure will not be executed. Your code should look like this.

```
$data = BrandEnquiry::whereHas('brand', function($query) use ($post){
                $query->where('id_brand', '=' , $post['id_brand']);
            })->when(isset($post['question']), function($query, $post) {
                return $query->where('subject', 'LIKE', '%'.$post['question']);
            })->when(isset($post['complaint']), function($query, $post) {
                return $query->orWhere('subject', 'LIKE', '%'.$post['complaint']);
            })->when(isset($post['partnership']), function($query, $post) {
                return $query->orWhere('subject', 'LIKE', '%'.$post['partnership']);
            })
            ->with('brandOutlet')
            ->with('user')
            ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
            ->get();
```

read docs here [laravel when](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)